# display the text on 2 different lines

Tags: c#

```
listBox2.Items.Add(c[n].nume_proprietar + ", " + c[n].nume_catel + ", " + c[n].varsta + " ani , " + c[n].data_vaccin + " " + c[n].tip_vaccin);
```

Hi, I was wandering if i could insert a line in between `" ani , "` and `c[n].data_vaccin` so that my code will display on 2 different lines, obviously with the vallues i insert when i will run the program:

**c[n].nume_proprietar  ", "  c[n].nume_catel  ", "  c[n].varsta + " ani , "** and on another line

**c[n].data_vaccin  " "  c[n].tip_vaccin**

Comment: A `ListBox` will “ignore” or remove any line breaks for the added item. You will need to either add the second part as a “new” item to the list box OR use another control like a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `Environment.NewLine` where you want to breakline. It is environment specific and provides clarity over "\r\n" hence it's preferred to use.

```
listBox2.Items.Add(c[n].nume_proprietar + ", " + c[n].nume_catel + ", " + c[n].varsta + " ani ," + Environment.NewLine + c[n].data_vaccin + " " + c[n].tip_vaccin);
```

Comment: it didn't work, i dont know why